# SSH asks password even so key has been added

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, rsa, suse

I generated a ssh key for "ansible" user and it works all clients but one has SuSE (SLES) 11.4 OS.

Host side ~/.ssh directory content:

```
-rw-------.  1 ansible ansible  1675 May 14  2018 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--.  1 ansible ansible   401 May 14  2018 id_rsa.pub
```

Host side home directory (~/.ssh):

```
drwxr-----.    2 ansible ansible       4096 Oct 14 15:25 .ssh
```

getenforce:

```
Disabled
```

Client side sshd_config:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Client side ~/.ssh directory content:

```
-rw------- 1 ansible users  802 Oct 14 15:25 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 ansible users  173 Oct 14 15:40 known_hosts
```

Client side ~/.ssh directory:

```
drwx------ 2 ansible users  4096 Oct 14 15:40 .ssh
```

Debug:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ClientSide" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ClientSide [clientIP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansible/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansible/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ClientSide:22 as 'ansible'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts:203
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ClientSide
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:zQKgaQwXjAFWT0EHm57K9xl9cJ87fh671pmqExf7h6w
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts:203
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ClientSide
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts:150
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from clientIP
debug1: Host 'ClientSide' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts:203
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa (0x56394e960730)
debug2: key: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
```

Comment: Remove `RSAAuthentication`, as it's not a valid option for a [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config).  You'll need to review the OpenSSH server's log file to ascertain what the issue is, and you'll likely want to change the logging level to `LogLevel DEBUG3`

Comment: I removed the line. Now, how can I add the output of the "ssh client -vvv" command to here? It's too long.

Comment: You'll use a code box for the log output _(please do not edit the log output, as each line should begin with `debug`_).  Use the three backtick method, with an example being on the formatting bar - Click the ? mark > click Code > backticks are the second option, with the content beginning "_Markdown and HTML..._".   Please _**anonymize**_ any sensitive info, such as WAN IP, DDNS, SSH Server port #, hostnames, etc.  Please remove all log output from the file, start/restart the SSH server, try to connect with SUSE client, then post the output, as that's the only content that needs to be reviewed

Comment: Issue appears to begin 42 lines from the bottom, however, it's not immediately clear to me why the `id_rsa` key isn't being accepted.  Have you tried copying the private and public key for `id_rsa` from one of the working clients to the SUSE PC _(rules out any kind of corruption of the private/public keys on the SUSE client)_...  I would also try clearing the SUSE client's key from `known_hosts`, and also compare SUSE's `ssh_config`  _(both system-wide & user)_ to the same on another working client.  That's the extent of help I can offer, as someone with more knowledge will need to chime in.

Comment: [`ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) is for clients only: system-wide is located at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, whereas the user-specific one, if configured, is located at `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: According to the debug trace, your client is offering `id_rsa` to the server and the server isn't accepting it. Check the syslogs on the remote server to see if sshd logged the reason why it didn't accept the key.

Comment: I added a new user to both and I generated a key for this user. The new user can make an ssh connection without password successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was about client side home directory permissions. My ansible home directory (/home/ansible) permissions was 777 and I changed this to 755 and problem is solved.